# custom height for active admin table td not working in rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

In my active admin page i want all my td are in same height instead of increasing the height respective to content. I try to set height but its not working.

admin_custom.css.scss

```
    body.active_admin {
    table td{
    height: 36px !important;
    color: black;
    width: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    }
  }
```

[image: this is the image i have. I want my address to be displayed in a single line. And only a specified width has to be visible and by clicking it i can see the entire address.]

This is the image i have. I want my address to be displayed in a single line. And only a specified width has to be visible and by clicking it i can see the entire address

Comment: In your nested css example you don't close the `body.active_admin {` block but i don't know if you just neglected to paste it into the question.  Have you tried Chrome inspector?  That's always my first port of call with any CSS problems.  It will show you if another style rule is overriding the one you listed.

Comment: Yes i just forget to paste.In inspector what I saw.. body.active_admin table td {
height: 36px !important;
}                  table.index_table td {
padding: 10px 12px 8px 12px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
vertical-align: top;
}

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're using a javascript/css table-displaying plugin, is that right?  (I say that because of the little triangles which look like 'order by' buttons)  If so then it will probably be automatically assigning what it thinks are sensible widths to the columns.

If you display the truncated version, which shows the full address when clicked, then that might solve your width problem as well.  I would do this like so:

```
<%# in the td which has the address %>
<div class="truncated-address">
  <%= truncate(foo.address, length: 20) %>
<div>
<div class="full-address" style="display:none;">
  <%= foo.address %>
<div>
```

then add this to the javascript which is used on the page - i'm writing this in jQuery, you can rewrite it yourself if you're not using jQuery.

```
$(".truncated-address").click(function(){ $(this).hide().siblings().show();});
```